# Java - Is it possible to initialize all classes

Tags: java, class, initialization

I wondered if it is somehow possible to initialize all classes.

This is maily because I work in a environment where Reflection is basically missing. So my very first thought was to initialze all classes so that some classes that I want to register somewhere get registered there without having to type the code for all of them.

But I basically just noticed that it is impossible to statically instantiate an Object of the class without knowing which class it is.

So everything I asked for is somehow pointless and I am afraid I can't do what I initially wanted to do. Register a bunch of classes which I don't want to do by hand.

Also the functionality of the "Class" class is very restricted. I can't create an instance from a Class object which makes this entirely impossible (Neither can I call static stuff from the class object)!

*If more information is needed, please tell me.*

Comment: more information in needed.

Comment: More information is needed.

Comment: No. There are way too many classes with way too many dependencies. What are you actually trying to do? What is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: in c# you have something called reflection. From a assembly you can get all classes and from here you can do what you want..

Comment: @lordkain Java has reflections too.  How to do initialise all classes with reflections in C#.  Is there a method which returns all unloaded classes?

Comment: Do you mean instantiate instead of initialize?

Comment: @PeterLawrey : Sorry I dont know Java that well, this is just a  possible solution

Comment: There's a good article on how to do this here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-find-all-classes-in-package

Answer (score 5):

No, not all classes can be initialized.
Proof:

```
public class ThisClassCannotBeInitialized {

    static int ohGodWhy = 1 / 0;
}
```

Attempting to initialize this class will result in a `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`.

Comment: +1 for the literally correct answer ;)

Comment: he, thats what I said.. more or less anyway

Comment: @lordkain: No.. Not even close..

Answer (score 3):

What you suggest is highly unlikely a good idea.  What is done sometimes is to find all the classes with annotation or implement an interface.  There is a library which does this.

https://code.google.com/p/reflections/

> Reflections scans your classpath, indexes the metadata, allows you to query it on runtime and may save and collect that information for many modules within your project.
>
> Using Reflections you can query your metadata such as:
>
> - get all subtypes of some type
> - get all types/constructos/methods/fields annotated with some annotation, optionally with annotation parameters matching
> - get all resources matching matching a regular expression
> - get all methods with specific signature including parameters, parameter annotations and return type

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [JLS 12.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1):

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - T is a class and a static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant
>     variable (§4.12.4).
> - T is a top level class (§7.6), and an assert statement (§14.10)
>     lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.

So if you want to initialise all classes in your project at one point in time, then you'd have to iterate through your classes and do one of the above to each class you want to initialise. So can you? In theory, sure. In reality, if you *rely* on having to initialise every class in your project at one particular point in time, you've almost definitely gone about something the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any simple way of doing this.  You won't necessarily know the entire set of classes that your application will eventually end up loading.  You could traverse your entire classpath looking for classes, and load and initialize them one by one, but this is terribly inefficient, and you will likely end up processing many classes that you wouldn't have ever loaded anyway.

If you only need to initialize certain classes, either piecewise or from a predefined list, you could use a method like `RuntimeHelpers.encureClassInitialized()` below:

```
public final class RuntimeHelpers {
    private RuntimeHelpers() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Code is supposed to be unreachable.");
    }

    public static void ensureClassInitialized(final Class<?> clazz) {
        getUnsafeInstance().ensureClassInitialized(Objects.requireNonNull(clazz, "clazz"));
    }

    private static Unsafe _unsafe;

    private static Unsafe getUnsafeInstance() {
        if (_unsafe != null) {
            return _unsafe;
        }

        try {
            return (_unsafe = Unsafe.getUnsafe());
        }
        catch (Throwable ignored) {
        }

        try {
            final Field instanceField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
            instanceField.setAccessible(true);
            _unsafe = (Unsafe) instanceField.get(Unsafe.class);
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                String.format(
                    "Could not load an instance of the %s class.",
                    Unsafe.class.getName()
                )
            );
        }

        return _unsafe;
    }
}
```

**Be warned** that this code depends on JDK internals that could (in theory) change between releases or even be removed altogether.  It may not work at all on non-Oracle JDKs.

Answer (score -3):

This should do the trick

```
List<class> allClassess = HelloWorld.GetClasses();

foreach (currentClass class in  allClassess )
    currentClass.Initialize();
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. Is it supposed to be a tongue-in-cheek answer?

Comment: did you include the needed namespaces?

Comment: This appears to be a mix of Java and C# code, much of it invalid in either language.

Comment: namespaces? there isn't even a `foreach` keyword in Java.